# How to get rid of this warning -memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4'

Tags: angular

I have a warning after an update to Angular 16 that is showing up and it's

```
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
warning @angular-devkit/build-angular > webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware > memfs@3.6.0: this will be v4
```

In my package.json I only refer to @angular-devkit/build-angular, should I reference memfs as well?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "moonshine",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ci": "yarn install --frozen-lockfile",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:docker": "ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check --base-href=/",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production --extract-licenses=true && xcopy web.config dist\\ttg-crm",
    "build:linux": "ng build --configuration production --extract-licenses=true && cp web.config dist/ttg-crm",
    "build:staging": "ng build --configuration=staging --extract-licenses=true && xcopy web.config dist\\ttg-crm",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.6",
    "@angular/localize": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "@material/checkbox": "^15.0.0-canary.b994146f6.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^15.1.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^16.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^16.1.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler": "^13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-utils": "13.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.2",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^6.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.6.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "jsencrypt": "^3.3.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ngx-scanner-qrcode": "^1.5.8",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.20",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics" :"^16.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.196",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if that is a dependency in one of your other node modules? Most likely, looking at the node modules in your package.json, it's probably a dependency in one of those which is causing the issue and upgrading the package that is effected should fix it.

Comment: it starts from `@angular-devkit/build-angular`